# NaN poisson loss values for Neural Network regression

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, poisson

I'm trying to train a Keras Neural Network for regression. My dataset instances consit of two poisson distributions, one as input (a vector of four elements between 0 and 1) and the other as outupt ( as well as a vector of four elements between 0 and 1). So I read that *poisson loss function* could be an optimal loss function choice for this case. Below there is the configuration of my model

```
A_0 = Input(shape=(X.shape[1], ), name='input')
A_1 = Dense(32, kernel_initializer='he_uniform', activation='relu')(A_0)
A_2 = Dense(4, activation='linear')(A_1)
model = Model(inputs=[A_0], outputs=[A_2])
opt = Adam(lr=0.001)
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.Poisson(), optimizer=opt)
```

When I try to fit the model I obtain something like that

```
Epoch 1/200
625/625 [==============================] - 1s 530us/step - loss: nan
Epoch 2/200
625/625 [==============================] - 0s 451us/step - loss: nan
Epoch 3/200
625/625 [==============================] - 0s 474us/step - loss: nan
Epoch 4/200
625/625 [==============================] - 0s 449us/step - loss: nan
Epoch 5/200
625/625 [==============================] - 0s 484us/step - loss: nan
```

What could be the reason of nan loss ? (My dataset contains some zeros, but after scaling it I still obtain the same issue)

Comment: if your model returns negative values it results in a NaN loss due to the log ops

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So do you suggest me to use some other activation function for the output layer ? Or there are other ways to force the model to return positive values ?

Comment: yes, try `sigmoid`, activation function in your last layer and see how it performs.